# Scraping data from json response using twofold request

Tags: vba, json, web-scraping

I've written a script which is able to get javascript encrypted links from a webpage and then using those newly produced links by making another request It can reach the target page and going there it is capable of scraping necessary data from json response. It's working like magic. I tried to make the whole thing flawlessly. Here is what I did:

```
Sub Json_Twofold()
Const link = "https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/wsSearch.cfm?method=schoolDetail&businessId="
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, str As Variant, exstr As Variant

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/wsSearch.cfm?method=findSchools&searchTerm=All&radius=25", False
    .send
    str = Split(.responseText, "city"":""")
End With

y = UBound(str)
For i = 1 To y
    req = link & Split(Split(str(i), "businessId"":")(1), ",")(0)

    With http
        .Open "GET", req, False
        .send
        exstr = Split(.responseText, "mgrLast"":""")
    End With

    Z = UBound(exstr)
    For L = 1 To Z
        x = x + 1
        Cells(x, 1) = Split(Split(exstr(L), "city"":""")(1), """")(0)
        Cells(x, 2) = Split(Split(exstr(L), "businessName"":""")(1), """")(0)
        Cells(x, 3) = Split(Split(exstr(L), "email"":""")(1), """")(0)
        Cells(x, 4) = Split(Split(exstr(L), "web"":""")(1), """")(0)
        Cells(x, 5) = Split(Split(exstr(L), "phone"":")(1), ",")(0)
    Next L
Next i
End Sub
```